# How to containerize the web application built with angular and .Net framework?

Tags: .net, angular, amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-web-api

I have an application built using Angular10 as frontend and the backend is written using the .Net framework(+Entity framework). My database is SQL Server. I have two separate packages for production. One is the frontend package(dist folder) and the second is the backend package(published folder). I have also deployed the two packages separately on the server. But, present the requirement is to host the application in the cloud, and the cloud provider is AWS. Now, my doubt is like Do I need to create two separate containers or a single container? and, what about the database?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about .Net framework and the actual architecture you want to follow for your application, but there are two main AWS services you should definitely use.

**Elastic Container Repository** - Works as a personal Docker Hub for you. You can push and pull docker images.

**Elastic Container Service** - An orchestrator tool that handles your containers. This has a sub-service/component called **TaskDefinition** where you define the properties, volumes, environment variables for your Docker image just a like you would do with docker-compose.

Now, as I stated previously, it really depends what type of architecture you want. If you're going for monolothic type, you just need to create 1 Service in Elastic Container Service corresponding to one or two images, backend and frontend. I say one or two because again, as I stated previously, I don't know much about .Net framework but I do know Java SpringBoot and there's a way to pack everything from Angular in SpringApplication Jar, making it one Docker image.

If you wish to have everything seperate, with their own loadbalancer (if you're using them), health checks, auto-scalability and so on, you create 2 Docker images, managed seperately in their own Elastic Container Service.

Docker images can be created through the use of **Codebuild** or just create them locally and push to your private repository.

You can check some documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/what-is-ecr.html